# Java - Regular expression for date formats?

Tags: java, regex, date-format

How do I throw this into a regular expression where MON can be any three letter month and YYYY is the year, etc..?

```
MON ## - MON ##, YYYY
MON ##, YYY1 - MON ##, YYY2
MO1 ## - MO2 ##, YYYY
MON ## - MON ##, YYYY
```

Comment: Write the regular expressions for each case, and OR them together ("|") operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that would be

```
Pattern.compile
(
    "(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \\d\\d(, \\d\\d\\d\\d)?" +
    " - (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \\d\\d, \\d\\d\\d\\d"
)
```

(Note: you may need to tweak that to account for things that aren't clear in your question — for example, can the day-of-month be just one digit, or must it be two?)

But I have to wonder if this is the best way to do whatever it is that you're trying to do. Are you familiar with [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? (What exactly *is* it that you're trying to do?)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. 
I'm running a method where the dates are passed via a parameter such as:
Jan 04 - Jan 08, 2012
and
Dec 27, 2011 - Jan 03, 2012
and then checked to see if they follow this format with all possible months.

Comment: Ruakh, I think I accidentally deleted you comment - sorry.

Comment: @coder3: No, sorry, it's I who deleted my comment, after I saw that you had deleted the comment it was responding to. I'll have to think about your use-case. This regex won't really enforce that the argument is *valid* -- for example, it won't notice if a day-of-month is `00` or `32` or `99`, or if a year is `0000` or `9999`, or if the date on the right is earlier than the date on the left -- but it may nonetheless be useful as a "sanity-check".